# Solr : Server at http://localhost:8080//solr returned non ok status:500, message:Internal Server Error

Tags: solr, solrj

I keep getting this `error "Server at solr 8080 returned non ok status:500, message:Internal Server Error"` when I am trying to index text files on solr server using solrj api.

My code is as follows:

```
public void IndexData(String filePath,String solrId)
{
        try {

            String urlString = "http://localhost:8080//solr";
            HttpSolrServer  server  = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);


            ContentStreamUpdateRequest up 
              = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

            up.addFile(new File(filePath),"");

            up.setParam("literal.id", solrId);
            up.setParam("uprefix", "attr_");
            up.setParam("fmap.content", "attr_content");

            up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT,                     true,true);

            server.request(up);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

I am able to query the solr server using same server but while indexing data, why I am getting this error?

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Server at `http://localhost:8080//solr` returned non ok status:500, message:Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:372)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
    at dataAnalysis.dataIndexer.DataIndexer.IndexData(DataIndexer.java:41)
    at dataAnalysis.dataHome.DataHome.main(DataHome.java:13)
```

Comment: should the url be http://localhost:8080/solr ... remove the / before Solr as it should be single slash.

Comment: It didn't make any difference Jayendra.

Comment: whats the error in the solr logs ?

Comment: I have integrated solr into Apache tomcat. So when I see catalina logs of tomcat, I don't see any error. It is working normally.

Comment: @RohitDeshpande you can post this as an answer, so that other people if they have the same problem, could use your solution.

Comment: first you should fix your log4j configuration, this is maybe why you did'nt get logs from solr library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey great news I was able to solve the issue. Two changes required. First I edited solrconfig.xml to remove extra tab like  to  for every path and second change was to copy jars from /solr/contrib/extraction/lib to /tomcat/web-inf/lib folder. –